# ExtJS open window with max height

Tags: extjs, window

I am trying to open a window (Ext.Window) by clicking on a button (Ext.Button). The problem is that this window must have size 80% width and 100% height of the screen of the user, that is it should cover all the vertical space.

I am really not able to create a working example. The button I use is hiding/showing this window, which always has wrong size..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are looking for ***Ext.getBody().getViewSize()***. More Specifically, Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height and Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width

This should work in your button's handler -

```
new Ext.Window({
    title:'Hello World Window',
    html:'Am I the right size?',
    height:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width*0.8 //80%
}).show();
```