# displaying another window using extjs

Tags: php, extjs

I have a php page how can i show another window using extjs? So code i have so far is like this:

Can anyone show me how can this be done? I only want this done by extjs please dont tell other alternatives.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.2a/ext-all.js">
</script>
<script>
window = new Ext.Window({layout: 'border'}).show()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow is the code to show an Ext window. Tested and it is working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.2a/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.2a/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function(){

        var window = Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
                    title: 'Hello',
                    height:100,
                    width:100
                });
        window.show();

    })
</script>
```

Working on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmJm8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
new Ext.Window({
    title:'Hello World Window',
    html:'Am I the right size?',
    height:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width*0.8 //80%
}).show();
```

[ExtJS open window with max height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727148/extjs-open-window-with-max-height)

Comment: i tried this and nothing happens? <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.2a/ext-all.js">
</script>
<script>
new Ext.Window({
    title:'Hello World Window',
    html:'Am I the right size?',
    height:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width*0.8 //80%
}).show();

</script>